# Snowflake case statement is returning an error instead of the value specified within the ELSE clause

Tags: sql, merge, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to check if one or many fields already exists in a table so I can do a `merge into` statement using them.

I tried this:

```
select sat_sector_hkey,
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(select id from hub_sector)
    THEN (MERGE INTO ...)
END AS id
from sat_sector;
```

For testing, I used only one `case` statement, and replaced `merge into` with a `THEN...ELSE` values:

```
SELECT sat_sector_hkey,
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(select id from hub_sector)
    THEN '1'
    ELSE ''
END AS id
FROM sat_sector;
```

When this field does not exists, the query return an error instead of `''`:

> SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 23 invalid identifier
> 'ID'

I am using a `CASE`, because I need to check if a column exists or not, as I don't know if it exists or not due to some technicalities in our data coming from multiple sources.

Comment: The error is saying the `id` is not recognized.  Use a correct column name.

Comment: that is the issue @GordonLinoff, I am using a `case` as the field might not exists, due dynamic structure that I am receiving each time into snowflake stage, so I am doing `case` clause over some fields that might not exist.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  There may be a way to do what you want . . . depending on what you really need.  I'm also not familiar with `merge` allowed as a subquery.  Does Snowflake really allow that?

Comment: You can't execute sql statements like MERGE inside a CASE expression. A CASE expression is used to return a scalar value.

Comment: I just to merge field values into a specific table, if this or an array of some fields already exists in another table @GordonLinoff

Comment: I think your best bet is using Information_Schema.Columns to get the column availability. You are probably looking at a stored procedure with some conditional execution based on Information_Schema.Columns.

Comment: What @Error_2646 said id correct. This would need to be a stored Proc that checks the information_schema. You can't use a case statement to check if a column exists or not. You can use it to check if a column contains NULLs though if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Construct an object with the full row.
- Test if the constructed object has data for "ID".

```sql
create or replace temp table maybe_id
as 
select 1 x, 2 id;

select *, 
case 
   when object_construct(a.*):ID is not null
   then '1'
   else ''
end as id 
from maybe_id a
;
```

Works for me - it gives `1` when the column id has data, and `` when the column doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: What about the merge when id is `1`?

Comment: Can we do an insert into statement inside then ?

Comment: You can use the same code to return the id value -- I just fixed the code in the question, and you can use `object_construct(a.*):ID::number` to give you its value when it exists (and cast to number if it is one)